# People can see my site but I can't, what can be wrong?

Tags: web-development, security

I can't see my own site, but other people can. I tried private settings and I don't see firewall. It is so frustrating, it keeps saying:

> Hmmm...can’t reach this page
>
> Try this
>
> - Make sure you’ve got the right web address: `http://www.example.com`
> - Search for `http://www.example.com` on Bing
> - Refresh the page

Comment: Have you tried a different computer/smartphone, not connected to the same network? Maybe you have some entries in your /etc/hosts which point to a temp/testing adress?

Comment: yes it does work on my phone- But I have been on the site from here so many times? and this is the only one I cant see?

Comment: how can my network suddenly not see just my site? also this could happen for more people? then it can hurt the business??

Comment: It sounds like you are using IE or Edge browser.   Can you reach it in other browsers on the some computer.   What do Firefox and Chrome show?

Comment: Are you able to ping your site? Open CMD and type `ping YOURSITEURL`

Comment: It might be that your IP is blocked? Due to too many request or something like that …

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general purpose personal computer problem that has nothing to do with web mastering and should be asked on SuperUser instead.

Comment: I disagree that this question is off-topic and belongs on SuperUser.  It is clearly about their website and they state that they are worried that it may affect more than just them.   While the solution may end up being local to their machine, it could also be DNS as pointed out in the current answer.  If anything, I would close this as "too broad" because there are so many possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

If others can access the site, and when you switch devices, you can access the site, then it sounds a lot like an issue with the machine you're currently using.

Customized DNS records like modifications to `/etc/hosts` to point to a dev/staging site would explain it, so might the [TTL on DNS records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records), if you have updated DNS records recently.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try a different browser, if you haven't already.

2) Have you considered clearing your browser cache or tried a different browser?  Your site may also have ended up in a disapproved area of your browser settings, so maybe consider clearing your settings to the default.

3) If all else fails, calling your host provider can help you sort this out, as your IP address may be flagged for some reason.

I know that in the past, I've helped someone with their AT&T U-verse service fix a problem like this, because it would intercept their web traffic in some cases and throw up its own proxy page.  That was a hardware/firmware issue with AT&T's modem/router and they needed to fix it.  I don't know if it ever got fixed, but I do know a lot of people had issues with it on the web.  If you can try through a different device on the same network, and can get to the site, then you can likely rule this out.